# How to store the current login time of a user to database through

Tags: sql-server, class, methods, get

I want to store the current time of the system at the time of the user gets login.

```
public string getlgn(string userNametime, string passWordtime)
{
    var myUser = entity.MVCUsers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Username == userNametime && m.Password == passWordtime);
    //string s= lastweblogin(userNametime, passWordtime);

    // Get previous login
    var prevLogin = myUser.Lastlogintime;

    // Update with current login
    string currentime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    prevLogin = currentime;
    MVCUser tbluser = new MVCUser();
    entity.MVCUsers.Add(tbluser);

    //entity.SaveChanges();
    var userlogindate = myUser.UserID.ToString();
    return (userlogindate);
}
```

Comment: my question is, what is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to retrieve login_time information of the user from the sys.dm_exec_sessions table.

For instance:

```
select max (login_time) as last_login_time, login_name from sys.dm_exec_sessions group by login_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace your code with the following.

Use a datetime variable instead of a string and don't convert it to `.tostring`.

```js
public string getlgn(string userNametime, string passWordtime)
{

    var myUser = entity.MVCUsers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Username == userNametime && m.Password == passWordtime);
    //string s= lastweblogin(userNametime, passWordtime);

    // Get previous login
    var prevLogin = myUser.Lastlogintime;

    // Update with current login
    datetime currentime = DateTime.Now;
    prevLogin = currentime;
    MVCUser tbluser = new MVCUser();
    entity.MVCUsers.Add(tbluser);

    //entity.SaveChanges();
    var userlogindate = myUser.UserID.ToString();
    return (userlogindate);
}
```

Or else you can check this method for reference

```js
public ActionResult Index(UserLogin user)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Session["UserName"] = user.UserName.ToString();
            User us = new User();

            if (us.login(user))
            {
                int id = user.PK_UserID;
                user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
                us.updatelogintime(id,user);
                return RedirectToAction("AddUsers", "User");
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "  Invalid Username or Password";
        return View();
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: we need to put the method into try & catch block for not throwing error.?